# Angular test - set up a spy on a function of the SUT component before the component is created by TestBed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ng-mocks

I have an Angular component I am writing tests for. The SUT component has a function I need to spy on (not ideal as noted further below). I want to set up the TestBed so that the function already has a spy assigned when TestBed creates the component.

I know how to spy on the function once the SUT component has been created. But I suspect there is a way to do that declaratively, I just can't find it. One reason I need that for is that if the SUT component executes some functions right after the component is created (e.g. from the constructor), I need the spies on those functions to be in place before the SUT is created.

I also realize that SUT shouldn't normally have its elements mocked/spied, and I actually ended up rewriting my tests accordingly. But I am still curious whether the "SUT declarative spying" is possible.

I tried to achieve this with TestBed.configureTestingModule.overrideComponent but that doesn't provide access to individual component functions to override.

I also tried ng-mocks, hoping MockBuilder might have support for mocking one specific function of the SUT component, but no luck there either.

Comment: As far as I know, no, there is no way to spy on a component that hasn't been created yet.
This is one of the reasons why it's generally considered to be a bad idea to do initialization in a component's constructor. Maybe move that code to ngOnInit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can spy a method of SUT is to update its prototype before the creation of an instance of it:

```js
  let backup: any;
  beforeEach(() => {
    backup = TargetComponent.prototype.func;
    TargetComponent.prototype.func = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue('mock');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    TargetComponent.prototype.func = backup;
  });
```

An example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-scott-euy6dz?file=/src/test.spec.ts

Comment: Thank you. As a last resort for some testing scenarios, this is perfect.

Comment: I made a little improvement on @satanTime 's answer. His answer has a drawback that code coverage won't see the original function implementation as being executed.

Also, since this is a function on the SUT, it is sometimes important that the original functionality is executed too, besides also spying on the function.

All that can be resolved by replacing ".and.returnValue('mock')" with ".and.callFake(() => backup())".

In fact, wouldn't that be a cool feature to wrap up and support in mg-mocks ?